# How to remove duplicate lines in a text file in Bourn shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Hi we are trying to remove the duplicates in a .txt file using Bourne shell script.

Sample file contents are

```
asdfg, test
efgrso, test
asdfg, test
asdfg, test
```

and the desired output is

```
asdfg, test
efgrso, test
```

We tried below code and both awk command and sort command doesn't work. Appreciate your help on this.

```
for dir in FilePath/test/*; do

echo "Directory $dir";
cd $dir;
## /usr/xpg4/bin/awk '!seen[$0]++' testfile.txt;

sort -u testfile.txt;
cd ..
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using just bash

```
for dir in FilePath/test/*; do
  if [ -d "${dir}" ] ; then
    echo "Directory $dir";
    cd $dir;
    sort -u file > output.txt # write file contents without dupes to output.txt
    cd ..
  fi
done
```

Comment: Excellent :) Thanks a lot. Appreciate your help on this. It worked.

Comment: Kindly edit the reply. It should be sort -u file > file1;   And thanks again

Answer (score 3):

You can try with `awk`:

```
awk '!a[$0]++' file
```

This will not print the line if the line `$0` is already part of the array `a`.

---

If you want to remove duplicates for each file in your directory, you can use:

```
find FilePath/test -type f -name testfile.txt -exec awk '!a[$0]++' {} \;
```

If you want to remove duplicates among all files in your directory, you can use:

```
find FilePath/test -type f -name testfile.txt -print | xargs awk '!a[$0]++'
```

Comment: Awesome solution.

Comment: Script is getting executed successfully but the duplicated are not removed :(

Comment: Thanks a mill for replying :)

Answer (score 0):

Even if you name the variable dir, ...

```
for dir in FilePath/test/*; do

echo "Directory $dir";
cd $dir;
```

The shell will not accept this as restriction and try to enter a file FilePath/test/foo.bar

```
sort -u testfile.txt;
```

Just to stdout?

```
cd ..
```

If the cd had failed, the cd .. will go up one dir.

```
done
```

---

Improvement:

```
for dir in FilePath/test/*/; do
#                         ^ is a dir
  echo "Directory $dir"
  cd "$dir" # quote 
  sort -u testfile.txt
  cd ..
done
```

maybe you lack permission?

```
for dir in FilePath/test/*/; do
  echo "Directory $dir"
  cd "$dir"
  changefailed=$?
  sort -u testfile.txt
  if (( ! $changefailed )) ; then 
    cd ..
  fi
done
```

better: Don't change at all:

```
for dir in FilePath/test/*/; do
  echo "Directory $dir"
  sort -u "${dir}/testfile.txt"
done
```

Comment: The directory is returned runtime, so unable to use sort -u $dir/testfile.txt; command. Thanks for replying

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand `The directory is returned runtime`. The name is returned? To whom? How?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot filter the file in place, you need to create an intermediate file:

```
tmp_file="$(tempfile)"
sort -u testfile.txt > "${tmp_file}"
mv "${tmp_file}" testfile.txt
rm "${tmp_file}"
```

---

Alternatively, if you have a GNU awk:

```
gawk -i inplace '!seen[$0]++' testfile.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. Will try it out this too :)